# Why would this be a $T_1$-space?

Tags: general-topology, model-theory, first-order-logic

Let $L$ be a first order language, and let $F$ be the set of the sentences in $L$. Let $\simeq$ denote semantic equivalence between sentences (of course, according to the completeness theorem, this is the same as syntactic equivalence, but in the context I'm working in, semantics are used rather thab syntax); and let $T := F/\simeq$.

For $H \subset F$, let $H^*$ denote the union of all equivalence classes that intersect $H$ (letting $\pi : F\to T$ denote the canonical mapping, we have $H^* =\bigcup\pi[H]$). Set $\Phi^* := \{\Phi\}^*$ for $\Phi\in F$.

For $H\subset T$, let $\overline{H} := \displaystyle\bigcap_{\Phi \in F, H\subset \{\Psi^* \mid \Phi\models \Psi\}} \{\Psi^* \mid \Phi \models \Psi\}$ (where $\models$ is the semantic implication relation)

I am asked in an exercise to show that this closure operator makes $T$ into a topological space, which is $T_1$.

But this seems false, as in a topological space, $\overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset$, whereas here, if we let $p := (\exists x, x=x)^*$, then for all $\Phi\in F$, $\Phi\models \exists x, x=x$, and so $p\in \overline{\emptyset}$.

Moreover, if we decide to artificially add $\emptyset$ to this set, turning it into a family of closed sets, the resulting space cannot be $T_1$, because for any $q\in T$, $p\in \overline{\{q\}}$.

What do you make of this ? Did the exercise forget to mention something, or am I wrong for some reason ?

Comment: Doesn't $F$ have inconsistent statements? In that case how do you interpret $\Phi\models{\exists{x=x}}$?

Comment: Well if $\Phi$ is inconsitent, then for any $\Psi$, $\Phi \models \Psi$. Indeed, $\forall M, M$ is an $L$-structure $\implies  (M\models \Phi \implies M\models \Psi)$ (if $P$ is false, $P\implies Q$ is true for any $Q$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right on all counts: This definition of the closure operator does not define a topological space, but if you add $\overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset$, you get a topological space (and almost certainly this was the intended space), but *not* a $T_1$ space.

To give some context on what might seem like a bizarre definition, the set $F$ of sentences comes with a preorder $\models$. Two sentences $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent if and only if $\varphi \models \psi$ and $\psi\models \varphi$. Thus $T$ is the poset associated to the preordered set $F$.

Now the definition specifies that the closed sets in the topology on $T$ are exactly those which are closed upwards in the induced partial order on $T$. This kind of topology has a name, an [Alexandrov Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology#Duality_with_preordered_sets) (usually you take the upwards closed sets to be *open* in the Alexandrov topology, so we're really looking at the Alexandrov topology on $T^\text{op}$, the dual partial order).

The Alexandrov topology on a partial order is never $T_1$, unless the partial order is discrete (which $T$ clearly is not). However, it is always $T_0$ (you can also define the Alexandrov topology on any preordered set, and it will be $T_0$ iff the preorder is a partial order).

Maybe whoever wrote the exercise confused $T_1$ for $T_0$?

---

**Added:** I've looked at Grätzer's book. The situation is very strange: it's a standard exercise in logic to show that given a first-order language $L$, you can associate a topological space which is $T_1$, totally disconnected, and compact (a.k.a. a Stone space), and the compactness of these spaces is equivalent to the compactness theorem. But Grätzer just describes the wrong space!

Here's the real space you should use when you try to solve exercises 85 and 86:

Let $S$ be the set of all complete consistent $L$-theories. For every sentence $\varphi$, let $U_\varphi = \{T\in S\mid \varphi\in T\}$. Then a basis for the topology on $S$ is given by the family of (clopen) sets $\{U_\varphi\mid \varphi\text{ a sentence}\}$.

Comment: Uhm about your aside note, it seems to me that $\vdash$ is usually used for syntactic implication, or maybe I'm mistaken ? Well it seems that it couldn't be a mistake since the author (I can give the references to the exercise is needed) precisely said "Show that this operator makes $T$ into a topological space that is $T_1$ (that is, for $p\in T$, $\overline{\{p\}} = \{p\}$)", so it can't be a mistake.

Comment: @Max wow! I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that. I'll edit

Comment: I am curious to see the source. Would you mind giving the reference?

Comment: It's weird though because the exercise is part of a larger whole, trying to fully justify the given name "compactness theorem"... The reference is Grätzer's *Universal Algebra*, exercise 85 to chapter 6. I've changed the notations a bit but I don't think I've changed anything substantial. Maybe I have and someone who owns the book can correct me

Comment: Oh! In that case, I suspect the points of the space are supposed to be complete theories, not sentences. Let me try to verify with a copy of Gratzer, and then I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks ! So the exercice was indeed wrong ?

Comment: I have a question regarding your edit (the "correct" exercise) : isn't $S$ rather the set of all $L$-complete *consistant* theories, and $U_\phi := \{T\in S \mid \phi \notin T\}$ ? Because this seems to work and I get good results with this, whereas I don't with your version (maybe I'm just having trouble with the exercise, but I'm wondering)

Comment: 1. Yes, I'm used to saying "complete" when I mean "complete and consistent". I should have been more precise. 2. My definition of $U_\varphi$ is correct. But note that the complement of $U_\varphi$ is $U_{\lnot\varphi}$!

Comment: Ok for the first one, and yeah, sorry about the second one (I just find it clearer to define $V_\phi$ as $U_{\neg \phi}$ and use the $V_\phi$'s instead, but it's not important as you pointed out)